# Debugging Angular application in Rider/WebStorm doesn't work

Tags: angular, google-chrome, debugging, webstorm, rider

I'm currently trying to debug my Angular app with Ride/WebStorm (I tried both, but both had the same problem). First of all I should mention that the Angular App is delivered via an external webserver (of course the Angular App is built in debug mode anyway).

Here's my Debug-Configuration in the IDE:

[image]

The "webpack://"-Remote-URLs are correct, as the Chrome developer tools show:

[image]

But if I start the debugging in Rider/Webstorm it doesn't work. The IDE connects to Chrome, but breakpoints aren't working. In the Debug-Tab in the IDE is visible that the IDE cann't find the "webpack://" scripts (and therefore can't set the breakpoints):

[image]

Besides this I don't have any other special configurations in the IDE.

Comment: please can you recreate the issue in WebStorm and provide your idea.log (https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241085-Locating-IDE-log-files)? Problems debugging on https can be related to certificate issues

Comment: Yes, I use an own certificate, but I installed it in the Windows certificate store. Here is the log of WebStorm if I try to load the page, there are many errors: [Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/bVrAsCLJ). By the way: Unfortunately it is not possible to disable ssl. (I created the log with the latest WebStorm 2019.1, released some minutes ago)

Comment: can't see certificate errors in provided log - can you provide all idea.log* files from log folder? Exceptions show problems parsing the generated sourcemaps. But I've never met such issues when debugging Angular

Comment: This was the only file in this directory

Comment: strange - I can't see the log header in it, only a tail. Please restart the IDE, recreate the issue and provide a new log (the whole file, not just an extract from it)

Comment: Yes, I didn't though that the startup routine is relevant for this error. [Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/uVtrJYrY). JavaScript debugging startet at timestamp 2019-03-25 17:29:21,167

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190640/discussion-between-sumafu-and-lena).